# Google App Script - Function Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack-api

I'm trying to call a function that gets a channel ID when given a Slack Workspace and channel name. I can get the correct result within the function, but when I try to call the function elsewhere, it is returning undefined.

Function to get the channel ID `

```js
//GET CHANNEL ID FROM LIST OF ALL CHANNELS IN WORKSPACE
function getChannelID(workspaceName, pageLimit, channelName, nextCursor){
  var channelListResponseURL = 'https://slack.com/api/conversations.list';
  var payload = {
      'limit': pageLimit,
      'types': 'public_channel, private_channel',
      'cursor' : nextCursor
    };
  var options = createURLargs(workspaceName, payload);
  var channelListResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(channelListResponseURL, options);
  var channelListJson = channelListResponse.getContentText();
  var channelListData = JSON.parse(channelListJson);
  
  //iterate through each channel in the returned JSON object and sets the channel ID for the one matching the channelName
    for (var i in channelListData.channels){
      if(channelListData.channels[i].name == channelName){
        var channelID = channelListData.channels[i].id;
        Logger.log('FOUND CHANNEL ID: '+ channelID);
        return channelID;// IF CHANNEL ID FOUND, THEN EXIT getChannelID FUNCTION AND RETURN CHANNEL ID
      }
    }
      // IF NO CHANNEL ID IS FOUND, THEN CHECK TO SEE IF PAGINATION IS IN EFFECT, UPDATE CURSOR, AND RERUN getChannelID FUNCTION
      if (channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor && channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor != ""){
        nextCursor = channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor;
        getChannelID(workspaceName, pageLimit, channelName, nextCursor);
      } else { 
        // IF CHANNEL PAGINATION IS NOT IN EFFECT, OR REACHED LAST PAGE AND NO RESULT IS FOUND
        return 'No Channel Found in Workspace';
      }
}
```

`

I can clearly see the 'FOUND CHANNEL ID: CXXXXXX' string in the logger, so I'm sure it finds it properly.

But when I call this getChannelID from the main function, it is returning undefined.

```js
  var channelID = getChannelID(workspaceName, pagLimit, channelName, nextCursor);
  Logger.log(channelID);
```

The weird thing is this seems to work when the JSON object from Slack isn't paginated, but when the results are returned paginated, I just seem to get undefined.

Any ideas why the result it's returning is undefined, even though it works in the function?

Comment: just scanning it, i see pageLimit is spelled pagLimit in the main function call, could that param being throwing things off?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, that's not it. I've got a couple page limit variables, so while a little confusing, it is defined properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your recursive function, the value is not returned. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
if (channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor && channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor != ""){
  nextCursor = channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor;
  getChannelID(workspaceName, pageLimit, channelName, nextCursor);
} else { 
  // IF CHANNEL PAGINATION IS NOT IN EFFECT, OR REACHED LAST PAGE AND NO RESULT IS FOUND
  return 'No Channel Found in Workspace';
}
```

#### To :

```
if (channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor && channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor != ""){
  nextCursor = channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor;
  return getChannelID(workspaceName, pageLimit, channelName, nextCursor); // Modified
} else { 
  // IF CHANNEL PAGINATION IS NOT IN EFFECT, OR REACHED LAST PAGE AND NO RESULT IS FOUND
  return 'No Channel Found in Workspace';
}
```

#### Note :

- When `channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor && channelListData.response_metadata.next_cursor != ""` is true, no value is returned. So I added `return`.

If this didn't work yet, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Added :

In my understanding, when the recursive function is run, the process returns to the line which was run. In order to confirm this, I prepared 3 sample functions.

Function 1

```
function foo1(value) {
  if (value == "") {
    foo1("bar");
  } else {
    return "ok";
  }
}
```

Function 2

```
function foo2(value) {
  if (value == "") {
    return foo2("bar");
  } else {
    return "ok";
  }
}
```

Function 3

```
function foo3(value) {
  if (value == "") {
    foo3("bar");
  }
  return "ok";
}
```

When these functions is run by as follows,

```
var res1 = foo1("");
var res2 = foo2("");
var res3 = foo3("");
```

`res1`, `res2` and `res3` are `undefined`, `ok` and `ok`, respectively.

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks! But I have no idea why. Why does it not completely exit out of the getChannelID function as soon as the workspace names match and it gets to return channelID? If channelID is set and the immediate next command is to return that channelID, why was it returning undefined?

Comment: @Dan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. But I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I added a sample script. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.